# How can I analytically find the period of the function $y=\cos(\pi t)\sin(t)$?

Tags: periodic-functions

That is, how can one solve the equation

$\cos(\pi t)\sin(t) = \cos[\pi(t+T)]\sin[t+T]\text{ for all } t\in\mathbb{R}^+$

for $T$ assuming that $T$ is also a positive real? I have tried using a whole load of trig identities and tricks but frankly, it's just a mess and I don't want to regurgitate that nasty stuff here. Upon plotting the function I can see that $T\approx 50$ (that it indeed has regular periodicity on a seemingly large-ish interval) but I have no idea how to determine this analytically. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: there is no such period $T$. Related: [Period of the sum/product of two functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions).

Comment: I'm supposed to find the Fourier series for this thing. Does this mean that there is no such series? Have I not looked closely enough at my plot such that I have been deceived?! If there's no period then it's really close. Anyway thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Comment: Technically not, but that depends on the context. See [Can a non-periodic function have a Fourier series?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115240/can-a-non-periodic-function-have-a-fourier-series).

Comment: wow, you're very helpful off the cuff. Thanks very much! Seems I have much to learn here

Comment: `If there's no period then it's really close.` Note that $cos(r t) cos(t)$ *is* periodic for any rational $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. For example, replacing $\pi$ with its well known approximation $\frac{22}{7}$ gives the function $cos(\frac{22}{7} t) cos(t)$ with the period $14 \pi \approx 44$ which is in the ballpark range of $50$.