# Separation of Variables vs Fourier Transform (for PDE)

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, systems-of-equations

I would like to know how can I know if I have to solve a PDE (Heat Equation, Laplace Equation, Wave Equation, etc.) using Separation of Variables or Fourier Transform.

Which boundary conditions do I have to see? What's the difference?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221137/difference-between-fourier-series-and-fourier-transformation

Comment: @Mattos thanks for the answer. I already read that thread, but that's not my question. I know Fourier Series are just for periodic functions, but, expanding a function, I can put it always as a periodic function (for example, if it's given between 0 and a, I can put that the same happens from a to 2a and it's periodic). So, how can I know if I have to use one or another, looking at the BOUNDARY CONDITIONS?

Comment: Yes, look domain. Infinite domain $\implies$ Fourier Transform.

Comment: @Mattos I have some exercises where $0<x<2$ and $t>0$ and I have to use Fourier Series (it's infinite in t) and I have to solve a Wave Equation. On the other hand, I have some exercises where $0<x<2$ and $y>0$ and I have to use Fourier Cosine Transform to solve a Laplace Equation. Then, I have another with $y>0$ (x can be any value) and I have to use Fourier Transform to solve Laplace Equation. Any more help? :S

Comment: I'll write a post.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, $t$ is a *parameter* in these situations. Being infinite in $t$ was not what I meant when I said infinite domain $\implies$ Fourier Transform..

However, $x$ and $y$ are *dimensions*, these are what I meant when I said infinite domain $\implies$ Fourier Transform. Notice in your last two examples, your PDEs depended on $x$ and $y$ but *not* $t$, and you needed to Fourier Transform both of them. This is because the domain of $x$ or $y$ (or both) in those examples is *infinite*.

So, in summary

**1.** If you see $t \gt 0$, that *does not* mean you have an infinite domain.

**2.** If you see $x, y \in (-\infty, \infty)$ or some variation of this, use Fourier Transform. If the domain is discrete (i.e. $x, y \in (a, b), \ a, b \in \mathbb{R}$) then use Fourier Series.

Comment: If you need anymore help, just ask below this comment. Also, if you're happy with my answer, could you please accept and upvote so we can close the question.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks, @Mattos