# Summary of different Fourier Transforms / Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am currently writing my PhD and would like to display a table summing up the different kind of Fourier Transforms and Fourier Series.
Here is the table I got from my different readings (mostly *Oppenheim, A. V., Schafer, R. W., & Buck, J. R. (1999). Discrete-time signal processing* and *Percival, D. B., & Walden, A. T. (1998). Spectral analysis for physical applications*):

[image]

Is this table right?

Comment: If I answer, do I get mentioned in the thesis?

Comment: For periodic, continuous input, continuous output, the Fourier transform is different from the Fourier transform in the non-periodic, continuous input case, because what is typically called the "Fourier transform" is defined on $L^1$ functions.

Comment: @Chester Sure! And if you give me your email I'll even send you a pdf so you'll be able to check...:)

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Are they both called the same way? There is also a mention of this in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221137/difference-between-fourier-series-and-fourier-transformation?rq=1), i.e. the Fourier transform can be applied on one period only of the continuous periodic function

Comment: I don't know whether they are *called* the same thing, but I do know they are *not* the same thing. Unfortunately I think mathematicians and engineers generally have disagreements over terminology and notation. In truth, everything in your table is a type of Fourier transform.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice article about the different kind of Fourier transforms as well as their interpretation is available on the Gaussian Waves website : http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2015/11/interpreting-fft-results-complex-dft-frequency-bins-and-fftshift/

Comment: you know that the Fourier transform of tempered distributions generalizes all this ? it let us understand what happens when the sample rate or the periodicity tends to $\infty$ and how one transform is the limiting case of another (so that all the Fourier transforms are limiting cases of the discrete Fourier transform)