# Frequency multiples in Fourier Series expansions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

When we expand signal with Fourier series, why angular frequencies are in multiples? I.e. why $$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}z_k*e^{jk\omega_0t}=z_0+z_1e^{j\omega_0t}+z_2e^{j2\omega_0t}+z_3e^{j3\omega_0t}+...$$
(negative terms are left out in order to save space).

My question is why frequencies are multiples of each other. For example why don't we expand in the following way: $$x(t)=z_0+z_1e^{j\omega_0t}+z_2e^{j2.4\omega_0t}+...$$ (note that we used $j2.4\omega_0$ instead of $j2\omega_0$)

Answer (score 0):

Your question basically exposes the difference between the Fourier Series and the Fourier Transform:

The Fourier Series is applicable to periodic signals only, and decomposes it into an infinite ***discrete sum*** of sines and cosines whose frequencies are ***integer multiples*** of the fundamental frequency.

The Fourier Transform, on the other hand, can be applied to both periodic and non-period signals. If it is applied to a periodic signal, it results in a series of delta functions at the frequencies of the signal's Fourier Series, with scaled amplitude. If it is applied to a non-periodic signal, then it results in a function evaluated at all ***real multiples*** of the fundamental frequency.

In fact, the coefficients of the Fourier Series can be seen as the Fourier Transform of the periodic signal evaluated over a single period, for integer multiples of the fundamental frequency. Whereas the Fourier Transform of a signal is an integral evaluated over all $\mathbb{R}$, with omega also taking any value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Very nice answers to a similar questions can also be found on: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221137/what-is-the-difference-between-fourier-series-and-fourier-transformation) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34028/21097)