# Performing and interpreting a Fourier Transform with the Excel Data Analysis Pack

Tags: analysis

I am confused about how to perform a discreet fourier transform in excel and what the output means. There are many math.stackexchange questions about this topic (see for example [Fourier transform for dummies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/fourier-transform-for-dummies)). but I am specifically interested in how to do it in Excel

Here are the first 20 rows of my spreadsheet:

[image: FFT in excel]

Here are the formulas I used (I used the FFT function in the data analysis

[image]

A description of what I did is as follows:

1. I wrote input values 1 to 64,
2. From each of those values I computed 3 cosine functions using Cosine(Input*3), Cosine(Input*4), Cosine(Input*5)
3. I added all of the values together
4. I ran the Fourier analysis tool on the values
5. I broker out the results into real, imaginary and absolute values

What I want to do/don't know:

1. I would like to plot some the sinusoids that correspond to the output and add them together to see how well they approximate the function.
2. I also don't know how to get the correct frequencies. The graph is symetrical and I think the frequency in the middle is 0.5 Hz (given that the original sample points are spaced 1 second apart).
3. I added together three cosine functions, shouldn't the graph of the absolute coefficents have only 3 peaks? (disregarding all values above 32)