# Why isn't $f(z)=\bar{z}$ complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-riemann-equations

It is quite easy to see why $f(z)=\bar{z}$ isn't complex differentiable.

$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=1\neq-1=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}$

But I struggle to see why this is the case.

Visualization of the conjugate function in my head is simply flipping the complex plane upside down. I don't see how this creates any discontinuities.

Am I having the wrong visualization or have I misunderstood complex differentiability?

Comment: The map $f$ is not complex differentiable because it reverses orientation, just like the mirror  in your room. What could be more visual?

Comment: "It is quite easy to see why $f(z)=\bar{z}$ isn't complex differentiable [...] But I struggle to see why " - Ok.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Viewed as a *real map* the complex conjugation map $z \mapsto \bar z$ *is* differentiable (in fact, linear): Under the usual identification $\Bbb R^2 \leftrightarrow \Bbb C$, $(x, y) \leftrightarrow x + iy$, it is given by $(x, y) \to (x, -y)$.

On the other hand, it is not *complex*-differentiable, which is a *much* stronger property. By definition, $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z_0$ if the usual limit
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{h}$$
of the difference quotient of $f$ exists, in which case we define $f'(z_0)$ to be its value. Critically, $h$ is here a *complex* variable: In the case of the conjugation map, the limit simplifies to
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\bar h}{h},$$
and for real $h$ we have $\frac{\bar h}{h} = \frac{h}{h} = 1$, but for imaginary $h$ we have $\frac{\bar h}{h} = \frac{-h}{h} = -1$. Thus, the limit does not exist for any $z_0$, and the map is not complex-differentiable anywhere.

Comment: quick question why h bar become -h?

Comment: @EM4 When $h$ is purely imaginary, complex conjugation simply flips its sign, since $\operatorname{Re}(h) = 0$.

Answer (score 29):

Of course it doesn't satisfy one of the possible definitions (Cauchy-Riemann equations, the specific limit does not exist), but in my opinion that doesn't give you much intuition - at least of the geometric kind. Hopefully the following will compensate for that.

TL;DR:

> If $f$ is differentiable at a point $z_0$, then there's the linear
>   function $$(Df)(z_0)\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C;\quad z \mapsto f'(z_0)z
>  $$ that approximates $f$ well around $z_0$. Multiplication by a
>   complex number is a rotation or a scaling of the complex plane, thus
>   it keeps orientation.
>
> These imply that $f$ has to keep
>   orientation locally, around $z_0$. Conjugation is a reflection so it flips
>   orientation, therefore it cannot be differentiable at any point in the complex
>   sense.

If $f\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is complex-differentiable, then it is differentiable as an $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ function, and it locally almost keeps angles and circles. To see this, look at one equivalent version of the complex-differentiability:
$$f(z_0 + re^{it}) = f(z_0) + re^{it}f'(z_0) + \omicron(r), $$
where $z_0 \in \mathbb C, 0 \leq r, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.
In fact, as a demonstration have a picture of the image of two circles around $1 + i$ by $\operatorname{id_{\mathbb C}}^2$.

The black,$\{z_0 + re^{it} \mid t \in [0,2\pi]\}$ ones are our original circles , 
the reds, $\,\,\color{red}{f(\{z_0 + re^{it} \mid t \in [0,2\pi]\})}$  are the blacks' images by $f$, and 
the blues, $\color{blue}{\{f(z_0) + re^{it}f'(z_0) \mid t \in [0,2\pi] \}}$ are the first order approximation of the red ones.

If we pick $z_0 = 1 + i, r=0.1$ and $0.2$, then we get, in order:
[image: r=0.1, r=0.2]

As you can see in the $r=0.1$ case the red and blue circles are almost equal. As $r \to 0$, the difference becomes smaller and smaller. That's what I meant by locally almost keeping circles.

Here's another picture, displaying the image of a point from each of the two black circles. The black and blue circles represent the same as before, the green circles are due to the $\omicron(r)$ part.

Look for the points $\color{red}{a}, \color{blue}{a'}, \color{red}{f(a)}$ and $\color{purple}{b},\color{blue}{b'}, \color{purple}{f(b)}$.
[image]
 In fact, in the $r=0.1$ case the green circle is so small, you can barely see any of it (this is why the red and blue circles from a moment ago were almost equal).

As you can see, the image of a circle is essentially the sum of multiple circles, in this case, two; however, if $f$ has lots of non-zero derivatives, then there'll be lots of circles, and each "new" circle will have smaller radius, but higher frequency than the previous one (assuming $r < 1$).

If you know about Fourier-series, then this concept might sound familiar. By the way, if you haven't already, read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72479/94959) answer.

Anyway, this is not so surprising: if you consider the Taylor series of a holomorphic $f$ at a point, and plug in a point from a circle around that point, you'll get
$$ f(z_0 + re^{it}) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}r^ne^{int}.$$
Here the $n$th term will correspond to the circle $\left\{\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}r^ne^{int} \mid t \in [0,2\pi]\right\}$.
OK, back to the original question.

Hopefully I've convinced you that the $\omicron(r)$ part is not significant. (Of course only so if the first derivative is non-zero, but in the other cases we can say something similar too.)

Let's say a word about locally almost keeping angles. Remember
$$f(z_0 + re^{it}) = f(z_0) + re^{it}f'(z_0) + \omicron(r).$$
Picking two numbers, $z_0 + re^{it}, z_0 + re^{is}$ the angle between them that is kept locally is $(t-s)$. Their images are 
$$ f(z_0) + re^{it}f'(z_0) + \omicron(r), \text{and } f(z_0) + re^{is}f'(z_0) + \omicron(r). $$
As you can see, the local (i.e. looking from the point $f(z_0)$) angle between them is again, approximately $(t-s)$.

Now let's really get back to your original question.
For $f(z) = \bar z$, assuming differentiability at $z_0$, the following would be true for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$:
\begin{align}
f(z_0 + re^{it}) &= f(z_0) + re^{it}f'(z_0) + \omicron(r) \\
\iff re^{-it} &= re^{it}f'(z_0) + \omicron(r).
\end{align}
This is absurd. Of course we could also note that conjugation locally flips angles. Going back to our points $z_0 + re^{it}, z_0 + re^{is}$, the angle is still $(t-s)$. Their images now are $$\bar{z_0} + re^{-it}, \text{ and } \bar{z_0} + re^{-is}, $$ meaning that the appropriate angle is $-(t-s)$. Thus again, conjugation can not be complex-differentiable.

Comment: Very nice answer, +1.

Answer (score 3):

$f$ does not create any discontinuities ! $f$ is continuous, but not complex differentiable.

Let $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ and $t \in \mathbb R$. Then:

$\frac{f(z_0+t)-f(z_0)}{t}=1 \to 1 $ for $t \to 0$,

but

$\frac{f(z_0+it)-f(z_0)}{it}=-1 \to -1 $ for $t \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

To be complex differentiable (**holomorphic**) require more than **differentiability** for a real function (that, anyway, is [more than continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity)) because we need that the limit of the incremental quotient have to be the same ''from any direction'' in the Argand Plane. You can see a good illustration of the case $f(z)=\bar z$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function).