# Differentiable everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

So I want to show that $f(z)=|z|$ where $z$ is a complex number is not differentiable anywhere, and that $g(z)=|z|^2$ is differentiable at $z=0$ only. 
Now with some computation, I got:

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|z+h|-|z|}{h}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $\lim_{ih\rightarrow 0}\frac{|z+ih|-|z|}{ih}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y}{i\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Thus they are not equal for $z\ne x+iy.$

Now what I do not get it is, this result would imply what I have to prove in the question, but why would this mean that this $f(z)$ is not differentiable anywhere?

Similary, for $g(z)$, the computation I get for $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|z+h|^{2}-|z|^2}{h}=2x$ and $\lim_{ih\rightarrow 0}\frac{|z+ih|^{2}-|z|^2}{ih}=\frac{2y}{i}$, this is not equal unless $z=0$. The conclusion once again is $g$ is not differentiable unless at $z=0.$

**Questions**

**1)** Why is $f$ not differentiable anywhere? Is it because the only possible place where it is differentiable is if $z=0?$, but that would imply the denominator is $0 $ and hence undefined?

**2)** Why do we have to have the condition in which the partials have to be equal in order for the function to be differentiable at some given domain?

I would appreciate some clear explanation. Thank You.

Comment: If $|z|$ is differentiable, then so is $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$. However, that function can't be differentiable outside of any neighbourhood of $0$, since assuming otherwise, we could divide by $z$ and get a differentiable function, but the result, $\bar{z}$ is not differentiable, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2199702/94959.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using partial derivatives here. It's more basic than that. The function $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ because the limit$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h|}h$$doesn't exist. And it doesn't exist because if you take $h\in(0,+\infty)$ then the limit is $1$, and if you take $h\in(-\infty,0)$, the limit is $-1$.

This doesn't prove that $f$ isn't differentiable anywhere. It only proves that it is not differentiable at $0$.

Now, the function $g$ *is* differentiable at $0$, because$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(h)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\overline h}h=\lim_{h\to0}\overline h=0.$$But it's differentiable only there. You can prove it using the Cauchy-Riemann equations: $g(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(w,y)i$ with $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $v(x,y)=0$. And you only have $u_x=v_y(=0)$ and $u_y=-v_x(=0)$ when $x+yi=0$.

And if $f$ was differentiable at a point $z\neq0$, so would be $f^2$, which is $g$.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and as much as I get this, I want to try and understand if my working in the above is correct. And if so, why the different partials imply the non-differentiability of the complex function.