# Summation interchange in DFT/FFT

Tags: summation, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Let $x(n)$ be a sequence of length $N = LM, n = 0,\dots,N-1$.$N$ and $M$ are integers.

The Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of $x(n)$ is given by

$X(k) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}x(n)W^{nk}_N$

where $W_N = e^{\frac{-j 2 \pi}{N}}$.

Let $n = l + mL$ and $k = q + pM$

$0 \le l,p \le L-1$, $0 \le m,q \le M-1$

$X(p,q) = \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}(\sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}x(l + mL)W^{(l + mL)(q + pM)}_N)$.

$W^{(l + mL)(q + pM)}_N = W^{lq + lpM + mqL + mpLM}_N = W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N$

Since $W^N_N = 1$.

$X(p,q) = \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}\sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}x(l + mL)W^{lq + lpM + mqL}_N  ... (1)$.

Why the above equation (1) can be written as
$X(p,q) = \sum_{l = 0}^{L-1}\{W^{lq}_N \sum_{m = 0}^{M-1}x(l + mL)W^{mq}_M \} W^{lp}_L$

after summation interchange of indices $l$ and $m$.

Can you explain the method behind the the interchange of indices $l$ and $m$ in detail.

I have taken the above material from the book:Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms and Applications, 5th edition

https://www.pearson.com/en-us/subject-catalog/p/digital-signal-processing-principles-algorithms-and-applications/P200000003415/9780137348657

Comment: By the way, the discrete Fourier transform is much more clear using the language and notation of linear algebra: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944778/40119

Comment: I wish to connect both linear algebra and the summation reps of DFT

Comment: Generally, cross-posting is frowned upon…